# How to reload current page when destroy a micropost with AJAX in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

guys! I'm start to learn RAILS.
I have a list of micropost using pagination. And when I destroy a micropost, it go to first page. But I want when I destroy a micropost, it will reload a current page.

This is my code:

*static_pages_controller.rb*

```
def home
    return unless logged_in?
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

microposts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referrer || root_url }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#microposts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/feed')) %>");
```

_microposts.html.erb

```
<% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", micropost, remote: true,
                                       method: :delete,
                                       data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
```

_micropost.html.erb

```
<ol class="microposts" id="microposts_profile">
  <%= render @microposts %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>
```

Do you have any idea to handle this problem?

Comment: You need to redirect to home but also pass in the page parameter

Comment: Does `params[:page]` in `destroy` action return the right page number?

Comment: @nsave it's not return page number, so I can't reload right page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `page` param to your delete request like this:

```
<% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", micropost_path(micropost, page: params[:page]),
                                   remote: true,
                                   method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm start to learn RAILS

Welcome!

---

Simple fix:

```
#app/views/microposts/destroy.js.erb
location.reload(); // Reloads current page (the :page param should be predefined from the URL)
```

---

Proper fix:

```
#app/views/microposts/index.html.erb
<%= render @microposts %>
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>

#app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb
<%= link_to "Delete", micropost_path(micropost, page: params[:page]), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"} if current_user? == micrpost.user %>

#app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate
   respond_to :js, :html

   def index
      @microposts = current_user.feed.paginate
   end

   def destroy
      @micropost = Micropost.find params[:id]          
      @microposts = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) if @micropost.destroy
   end

   private

   def authenticate
      return unless logged_in?
   end
end
```

This will allow you to update with the following:

```
#app/views/microposts/destroy.js.erb
$("#microposts").html("<%=j render @microposts %>");
```

Comment: No problem fella, I'm more interested in whether it *works* :)